# Dash Python: Add date-picker and sidebar to dashboard

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a sidebar and a date-picker in my dashboard built with Dash. However, I am unable to load the graph correctly based on the date range selected. The data source can be found in the link below, however, I changed the column "Year" values to dates in this format "YYYY-MM-DD".

[Data Source](https://www.kaggle.com/chubak/iranian-students-from-1968-to-2017)

Help is much appreciated.

**Output errors:**

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'iranian_students.csv'
```

```
ID not found in layout

Attempting to connect a callback Input item to component:
  "date-range"
but no components with that id exist in the layout.

If you are assigning callbacks to components that are
generated by other callbacks (and therefore not in the
initial layout), you can suppress this exception by setting
`suppress_callback_exceptions=True`.
This ID was used in the callback(s) for Output(s):
  students.figure
  students.figure
```

```
ID not found in layout

Attempting to connect a callback Output item to component:
  "students"
but no components with that id exist in the layout.

If you are assigning callbacks to components that are
generated by other callbacks (and therefore not in the
initial layout), you can suppress this exception by setting
`suppress_callback_exceptions=True`.
This ID was used in the callback(s) for Output(s):
  students.figure
```

**My code:**

```
# To add a new cell, type '# %%'
# To add a new markdown cell, type '# %% [markdown]'
# %%
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from flask import Flask
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import json_normalize
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pytz, time
from datetime import datetime, tzinfo, timezone, timedelta, date
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import random
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots


# %%
# constants
df = pd.read_csv('Bootstrap\Side-Bar\iranian_students.csv')
localTimezone = pytz.timezone('Africa/Cairo')
datetimeNow = datetime.now(localTimezone)


# %%
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.FLATLY],
                meta_tags=[{'name': 'viewport',
                            'content': 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'}]
                )


# %%
def serve_layoutOnReload():
    # styling the sidebar
    SIDEBAR_STYLE = {
        "position": "fixed",
        "top": 0,
        "left": 0,
        "bottom": 0,
        "width": "16rem",
        "padding": "2rem 1rem",
        "background-color": "#f8f9fa",
    }

    # padding for the page content
    CONTENT_STYLE = {
        "margin-left": "18rem",
        "margin-right": "2rem",
        "padding": "2rem 1rem",
    }

    sidebar = html.Div(
        [
            html.H2("Sidebar", className="display-4"),
            html.Hr(),
            html.P(
                "Number of students per education level", className="lead"
            ),
            dbc.Nav(
                [
                    dbc.NavLink("Home", href="/", active="exact"),
                    dbc.NavLink("Page 1", href="/page-1", active="exact"),
                    dbc.NavLink("Page 2", href="/page-2", active="exact"),
                ],
                vertical=True,
                pills=True,
            ),
        ],
        style=SIDEBAR_STYLE,
    )

    content = html.Div(id="page-content", children=[], style=CONTENT_STYLE)

    web_layout = html.Div([
        dcc.Location(id="url"),
        sidebar,
        content
    ])

    return web_layout


app.layout = serve_layoutOnReload
# app.layout = html.Div([
#     dcc.Location(id="url"),
#     sidebar,
#     content
# ])


# %%
@app.callback(
    Output("page-content", "children"),
    [Input("url", "pathname")]
)
def render_page_content(pathname):
    if pathname == "/":
        return [
                html.H1('Kindergarten',
                        style={'textAlign':'center'}),
                dbc.Container([
                        dbc.Row([
                            dbc.Col([
                                html.P("Date picker:", className='text-right font-weight-bold mb-4'),
                                ],xs=12, sm=12, md=12, lg=5, xl=5),
                            dbc.Col([
                                dcc.DatePickerRange(id='date-range', 
                                                    min_date_allowed=date(2020, 6, 1),
                                                    max_date_allowed=datetimeNow.date(),
                                                    start_date=datetimeNow.date() - timedelta(days=7),
                                                    end_date=datetimeNow.date(), ),
                                ],xs=12, sm=12, md=12, lg=5, xl=5),], no_gutters=True, justify='center'),
                        
                        dbc.Row(
                            dbc.Col(html.H2(" ", className='text-center text-primary mb-4'), width=12)
                            ),
                        
                        dbc.Row([
                            dbc.Col([
                                dcc.Graph(id="students", figure={}),
                            ], xs=12, sm=12, md=12, lg=5, xl=5),], justify='center')
                ], fluid=True)
            ]
    elif pathname == "/page-1":
        return [
                html.H1('Grad School',
                        style={'textAlign':'center'}),
                dcc.Graph(id='bargraph',
                         figure=px.bar(df, barmode='group', x='Date',
                         y=['Girls Grade School', 'Boys Grade School']))
                ]
    elif pathname == "/page-2":
        return [
                html.H1('High School',
                        style={'textAlign':'center'}),
                dcc.Graph(id='bargraph',
                         figure=px.bar(df, barmode='group', x='Date',
                         y=['Girls High School', 'Boys High School']))
                ]
    # If the user tries to reach a different page, return a 404 message
    return dbc.Jumbotron(
        [
            html.H1("404: Not found", className="text-danger"),
            html.Hr(),
            html.P(f"The pathname {pathname} was not recognised..."),
        ]
    )


# %%
@app.callback([Output("students", "figure")],
                [Input("date-range", "start_date"),
                 Input("date-range", "end_date")])
def update_charts(start_date, end_date):
    # read data upon refresh browser
    df = pd.read_csv('iranian_students.csv')

    # masks
    mask1 = (
        (df.Date >= pd.to_datetime(start_date))
        & (df.Date <= pd.to_datetime(end_date))
    )# daily sgym signups

    # filtered dataframes
    filtered_data1 = df.loc[mask1, :].reset_index(drop=True)

    # plots
    # daily sgym signups
    trace = []
    trace.append(go.Bar(
            x = filtered_data1['Date'],
            y = filtered_data1['Girls Kindergarten'],
            name = 'Count of students'
        ))
    
    # add moving average
    filtered_data1['Moving Avg'] = filtered_data1['Girls Kindergarten'].rolling(window=7, min_periods=1).mean()
    trace.append(go.Scatter(x=filtered_data1['Date'], y=filtered_data1['Moving Avg'], name = 'Rolling Mean=7'))
    
    students_fig = {'data': trace,
                            'layout': go.Layout(
                                {"title": {"text": "Student Count\n"
                                            '('+str(start_date)+' to '+str(end_date)+')', 
                                                "x": 0.05, "xanchor": "left"},
                                    "xaxis": {"fixedrange": False, 'title':'Date',   
                                                'tickmode':'linear', 'automargin':True},
                                    "yaxis": {"fixedrange": False, 'title':'Count of Signups'},
                                    'xaxis_tickformat':'%d %b',
                                    'title_font_size': 14,
                                    'hovermode':'closest',
                                    'legend_title_text':'Gym',
                                    'hovermode':'closest',
                                    },)   }
    
    return students_fig


# %%
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first error is telling you exactly where the problems start. The problem is in the file path that you define when updating the graph.

instead of this:

```
 def update_charts(start_date, end_date):
        # read data upon refresh browser
        df = pd.read_csv('iranian_students.csv')
```

You need to do this:

```
 def update_charts(start_date, end_date):
        # read data upon refresh browser
        df = pd.read_csv('Bootstrap\Side-Bar\iranian_students.csv')
```

the second problem is that you
call function serve_layoutOnReload without the brackets?

```
app.layout = serve_layoutOnReload
```

instead of

```
app.layout = serve_layoutOnReload()
```

The third problem is in how you define your layout. See [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/id-not-found-in-layout/49408) discussion for reference.[This](https://community.plotly.com/t/id-not-found-in-layout/49408) discussion from January is using the same code/database that you have and they are facing the same issues.

I would try defining the layout directly like this:

```
app.layout = html.Div([])
```

Comment: yes, you have more than one error. You should make separate questions for each error to get full answers.  I updated the answer.

Comment: i appreciate your attempts to help but have you actually run the full code ? I define app.layout to the actual function instance as per Dash guideline here, no parentheses: https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates